# MySQL - Multi-Row Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am looking for a way in MySQL to validate input with a trigger on more than one row at one time.   More specifically, I'd want to submit an update statement that updates 2+ rows (whereas each individual update would fire the trigger, but the entire update statement would not).

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER checkdistsum
AFTER UPDATE ON tests_detail

for each row

BEGIN

SET @totaldist = (select count(*) from (select sum(td.DISTRIBUTION_PCT) as
 total
from models m,.tests t,tests_detail td
where m.model_id = td.MODEL_ID and t.TEST_ID = td.TEST_ID
group by  t.test_id having total != 1)  as totalquery);

IF @totaldist > 0 THEN signal sqlstate '45000';

END IF;

END;//
```

The trigger will fire value of the query does not equal 1.  But I want that to only fire after the entire update statement gets executed.

An example of an update statement would be:

```
UPDATE tests_detail
SET DISTRIBUTION_PCT = (CASE 
  WHEN MODEL_ID = 3 THEN .40
  WHEN MODEL_ID = 2 THEN .60
  ELSE DISTRIBUTION_PCT 
END)
WHERE MODEL_ID IN(2,3);
```

In this case - the sum of the update statement would be 1.  However, if only one row gets updated at a time, the trigger would fire prematurely.

Comment: MySQL triggers always fire once for each row affected. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, so I can't suggest an alternative.

Comment: Thanks!  It doesn't have to be a trigger.  The concept would be that I'd run a check on a multi row update before the transaction gets committed to the database.  In the case I am looking for - I want to ensure all the rows that are updated sum up to 1.

Comment: before or after the update? Show the quer(ies)/constraints? It might be possible to wrap this in a transaction.

Comment: @danblack I made some edits on the question with some code examples.   Thanks.